# Proof verification: if $E$ is a finite dimensional subspace of a normed space $X$, then $E$ is a closed subspace.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, proof-verification

Could someone please verify the following proof for this statement:

> If $E$ is a finite dimensional subspace of a normed space $X$, then $E$ is a closed subspace.

---

Proof:

If $E$ is a finite dimensional subspace of normed space $X$, then $E$ is complete.

Let $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be a Cauchy sequence in $E$, where $x_n\to x$. We need to prove that $x\in E$. Let $E$ have basis $\{v_1,\cdots,v_d\}$.

We have for $n\gt m \gt N$, $\|x_n-x_m\|\lt \epsilon$, specifically, denote $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty = \{x^1_nv_1+x_n^2v_2+\cdots+x_n^dv_d\}_{n=1}^\infty=\{(x_n^1,x_n^2,\cdots,x_n^d)\}_{n=1}^\infty$

So $\|x_n-x_m\|=\|(x_n^1-x_m^1)v_1 + \cdots+ (x_n^d-x_m^d)v_d\|\lt \epsilon$

Which means $\forall i \in \{1,\cdots,d\}:\|(x_n^i-x_m^i)v_i\|\lt \epsilon$, which means each coordinate is a Cauchy sequence, converging $x^i_n v_i \to x^i v_i$, and hence in the span of the basis elements, and hence $x=(x^1,x^2,\cdots,x^d)\in E$.

So $E$ is complete.

---

If $E$ is a complete subspace of a metric space, then $E$ is closed.

This is because if $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$, $x_n\to x$ then since $x_n$ is Cauchy in $E$, and $E$ is complete, we have $x\in E$. So any arbitrary limit point of $E$ is contained in $E$.

---

Then $E$ being a finite dimensional subspace of normed space $X$, makes $E$ complete, and this makes $E$ closed.

---

Is this proof acceptable?

Comment: I think you have an omission partway through the first part.  You have a sum of vectors has norm less than $\epsilon$ and you conclude that each individual vector has norm less than $\epsilon$.  Since your basis was not necessarily orthogonal there may be cancellations in that sum I think.

Comment: In your proof that $E$ is complete you take a Cauchy sequence and assume it converges. To prove completeness you have to take an arbitrary Cauchy sequence and show that it converges to an element of $E$. You can't just assume that the Cauchy sequence converges.

Comment: @jooi Are you sure? I assume $x_n\to x$, and then I don't claim $x\in E$ until after I have shown that each coordinate in the finite basis converges into the span of the basis element

Comment: @JasonKnapp I think this is a good point, I will reconsider this, thanks

Comment: @I'mmostlyjustanidiot the assumption if ok if you assume that $X$ is complete.

Comment: @jooi Is it okay to say $x_n\to x$ where $x$ is in the completion of $E$? Oh wait, rereading what you said it sounds like you are saying that the completion of $E$ may not live in $X$.

Comment: If $X$ is complete then the completion of $E$ is a subset of $X$. But if $X$ is not complete, then this may not be true.

Comment: @jooi Thanks that makes sense

Comment: The deduction that $\|(x_n^i-x_m^i)v_i\|\lt \epsilon$ is not correct. To fix this, use the fact that all norms on a finite dimensional vector space are equivalent.